# Mesma partial view dentro de várias popup modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho um conteúdo que esta dentro de uma partial view. Tem situações em que preciso abrir *popup's* que mudam apenas os botões e suas ações.

Porém o conteúdo sempre é o mesmo da *partial view*. Acredito que ao renderizar a página, esta sendo criada a mesma *partial view* para cada *popup* e, com isso, os id's dos componentes HTML se repetem. Isso bagunça todo o código.

Por exemplo perde referência do *grid*, da *tabpage*.

Alguém sabe como reaproveito a mesma *partial view* em várias *popup's*?

```
<div id="divModal">
    @Html.Partial("DadosComuns")
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        dialog-01 = $("#divModal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Tela 01",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ação A": function() {
                    AcaoA();
                },
                "Fechar ": function() {
                    dialog-01.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        })

        dialog-02 = $("#divModal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Tela 02",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ação B": function() {
                    AcaoB();
                },
                "Ação C": function() {
                    AcaoC();
                },
                "Fechar ": function() {
                    dialog-02.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        })

        dialog-03 = $("#divModal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Tela 02",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ação D": function() {
                    AcaoD();
                },
                "Ação E": function() {
                    AcaoE();
                },
                "Fechar ": function() {
                    dialog-03.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Você precisa criar um exemplo em código. Eu imaginei do que se trata, mas não tenho como  ter certeza.

Comment: Vixi.... o código está muito grande.... vou tentar resumir:

Comment: Faça um [mcve].

Comment: Esse exemplo que coloquei acima serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi mudando os id´s dos elementos HTML.
Assim:
$("#grid").attr('id', 'grid-01');